# All disks show as Unconfigured Bad (UBAD) on RAID controller

Tags: lsi, megaraid, raid-controller, broadcom, storcli

Before starting, I will say I would appreciate help but really I need to hear from someone that has experienced this issue and how they solved it because the obvious and go to solutions are not working (believe me I have tried for a week).

With that said, if you know your LSI (now Broadcom) RAID controllers, then please read on.

> ***Problem***

All 10 of our 2TB disks are showing as UBAD (Unconfigured Bad) in the RAID provisioning utility after being formatted with the **sg_format** Linux utility.

**They were previously all working fine and set as JBOD disks.** Formatting rather than re-provisioning the disks was my fault for not knowing the repercussions.

[All disks show as UBAD (Unconfigured Bad)](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7tjIYaWvGGxxfjVPnMg-sdHTdIhl63RglTErTt7pgI43wgQg1XmmTvFcZK5L5iP3y-QV7BOLeaoWY11IyoMYX7_ICFHRmX9VUUR5nNXAOs4v0j-eYU9kKvkEiZ6FCSVHkcE0hEN21g=w684-h607-no-tmp.jpg)

The disks are Seagate ST2000NX0433 drives

The RAID controller is a Lenovo ThinkSystem RAID 930-8i card which is a rebranded Broadcom (formerly LSI) MegaRAID 9460-8i. The controller I/O chip is the SAS3508 I/O chip.

[The disks are being disabled by the RAID controller...](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fX5P881kcCG8G8LZxenTKEGfCN6H_XEowaKtcq700WONKCb00KxQsgJmLC9r7rWgYxi8QyUyAwvhpuNl-8awrqnrzdwOC6LXoSTqg9OCC1HAPde3y6kDeJXDxZyHkb1FGAckBH7mLA=w802-h646-no-tmp.jpg)

[despite them passing full diagnostic checks](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vBJPr73d2PWcAU0AiT7DxgM1hg_e7qIQH_rEUJonbG1ppjpSZN2-qL0DhnkXcPHCECJ79sLfmJpjBa64A5yXAKzXe-mimv6RKmz_uF-J5TXEDzCGc7Oyh_sFCdHz4ZqLyC45VCXEkA=w776-h717-no-tmp.jpg)

> ***What I've already tried***

1. Normally it should be possible to simply set the disks back to UGOOD or JBOD in the Manage Disk Drives section of the disk provisioning.
   Unfortunately all options are greyed out.

[Manage Disk Drives](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ODajg797QEqcI4Zbn2LOE9b0oWtL0cBjFhmzLx3mq7QuNB3UuobZkkB0-DSJmqW5OA7PMYsF18w7jcivsEoQw4lpmQKBNh8QF5rSXwRHqoxPXBJHg39sK-j-dE1XfZcEGBa1KFIn9w=w684-h607-no-tmp.jpg)

2. Running **different versions of storcli from an elevated** Linux shell results in Error code 255 'Operation not allowed' for any action that I try such as.

   ```
   linux:/opt/MegaRAID/storcli # ./storcli64 /c0 /eall /sall set good force
   CLI Version = 007.0813.0000.0000 Dec 14, 2018
   Operating system = Linux 4.12.14-lp151.28.13-default
   Controller = 0
   Status = Failure
   Description = Set Drive Good Failed.

   Detailed Status :
   ===============

   -------------------------------------------------
   Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                 
   -------------------------------------------------
   /c0/e134/s0 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s1 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s2 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s3 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s4 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s5 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s6 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s7 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s8 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   /c0/e134/s9 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
   -------------------------------------------------
   ```

or

```
    linux:/opt/MegaRAID/storcli # ./storcli64 /c0/eall/sall start initialization
    CLI Version = 007.0813.0000.0000 Dec 14, 2018
    Operating system = Linux 4.12.14-lp151.28.13-default
    Controller = 0
    Status = Failure
    Description = Start Drive Initialization Failed.

    Detailed Status :
    ===============

    -------------------------------------------------
    Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                 
    -------------------------------------------------
    /c0/e134/s0 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s1 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s2 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s3 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s4 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s5 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s6 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s7 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s8 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    /c0/e134/s9 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
    -------------------------------------------------
```

**There is nothing wrong with the RAID controller** because inserting other disks has them recognised manageable and usable.

> **Questions**

When I ran sg_format, I believe I have erased the metadata blocks used by the RAID controller for identifying disks (DOH).

**1. How do I restore or re-initialise the metadata?** (but remember storcli does not work)

Someone may mention the WebBIOS environment that is accessible on LSI cards by holding down Ctrl + H during POST.

[Maybe they'll think of this link](https://support.siliconmechanics.com/portal/kb/articles/recovering-foreign-unconfigured-bad-drives)

The problem is that Web BIOS is not enabled

```
    linux:/opt/MegaRAID/storcli # ./storcli64 /c0 show all | grep BIOS
    BIOS Enumerate VDs = 1
    Stop BIOS on Error = Off
    Enable Web BIOS = No
    Enable BIOS = Yes
```

**2. How do I enable Web BIOS?**

**3. Could I resolve this if I could format the drives with a good partition table in an external PC with a SAS controller card?**

Ok, thanks for reading. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what was the sg_format command you ran?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you resolve the it?

Comment: @Alek_A I'm sorry that I missed your question.

I solved it by buying a Silverstone 8 port SAS PCIe card for my PC and doing a lowlevel format on each disk.

It was awkward because I had to stick a tiny slither of tape over one of the pins of each drive connector, before the drive would be recognised.

This is to do with some power / mode sensing of certain SAS drives.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's interesting, could you please share the link where to read about this process, which pin to insulate, etc?

Comment: @Alek_A sure, here you go - https://forums.unraid.net/topic/84038-so-your-new-sas-or-sata-drive-wont-start-spin-up/

Comment: @Alek_A Or [this](https://zackreed.me/hgst-7k6000-not-spinning-not-working/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Now I know what to try next time.